# JPA @manyToMany with condition

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I got those tables :

> **User**: (user_id)
>
> **Site**: (site_id, subsite)
>
> **User_site**: (user_id , site_id)

I would like something like :

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinTable(
    name = "user_site",
    joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
    inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "site_id", referencedColumnName)
@Where(clause = "site.subsite = false")
private Collection<Site> sites;
```

But this doesn't work. Can I add a constraint on the site selection?

Answer (score 2):

Better than filtering on the SQL level, I recommend you to filter on the HQL level in Java using [Criteria](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html) in the overridden getter for the certain Collection.

Here is the example (untested):

```
public List getList(boolean subsite) {
    Criteria c = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(Site.class);
    c.add(Restrictions.eq("site.subsite", subsite);
    return (List<Site>) c.list();
}
```

Comment: What happens when you try to write back an entity like that to the DB?